# Enlazar tablas con el valor minimo (JOIN)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Es un tanto complejo, pero me intentare explicar:

tengo tres tablas, trabajadores, contratos y trabajos

**Contratos:**

```
    +---------------+--------+-----------------+
    | id_trabajador | sueldo | inicio_contrato |
    +---------------+--------+-----------------+
    |             5 |     13 | 31/11/2018      |
    |             6 |     14 | 31/11/2018      |
    |             5 |     16 | 01/01/2019      |
    |             4 |     13 | 31/11/2018      |
    |             6 |     16 | 01/01/2019      |
    |             5 |     20 | 20/01/2019      |
    +---------------+--------+-----------------+
```

**Trabajos**

```
+---------------+------------------+--------+
| id_trabajador | fecha_tabajo     | horas  |
+---------------+------------------+--------+
|             5 | 31/12/2018       |      8 |
|             6 | 31/12/2018       |      8 |
|             5 | 04/01/2019       |      8 |
|             4 | 04/12/2018       |      8 |
|             6 | 05/01/2019       |      8 |
|             5 | 06/01/2019       |      8 |
|             4 | 07/12/2018       |      8 |
|             6 | 07/01/2019       |      8 |
|             5 | 07/01/2019       |      8 |
|             4 | 08/12/2018       |      8 |
|             6 | 08/01/2019       |      8 |
|             5 | 08/01/2019       |      8 |
|             4 | 10/12/2018       |      8 |
|             6 | 10/01/2019       |      8 |
|             5 | 10/01/2019       |      8 |
+---------------+------------------+--------+
```

**Trabajadores**

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| id_trabajador |      nombre       |
+---------------+-------------------+
|             4 | Juan Flacido      |
|             5 | Maria Misericorda |
|             6 | Centollo Del Rio  |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

Entonces, como el contrato puede ir variando, necesito agrupar los trabajos por la fecha de contrato que le pertoque y hacer sumatorio de su sueldo (ya que el sueldo es por dia)

Por lo pronto tengo:

```
select SUM(c.sueldo), tr.nombre
from trabajo t 
INNER JOIN (select *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id_trabajador ORDER BY inicio_contrato ASC) rn
            from contrato) c 
            ON c.id_trabajador = t.id_trabajador AND fecha_tabajo > inicio_contrato 
INNER JOIN trabajador tr ON t.id_trabajador = tr.id_trabajador
GROUP BY  tr.nombre
```

Pero el problema lo tengo al enlazar el join, por ejemplo un contrato se firmo el 30/11/2018 y otro el 01/01/2019, un trabajo que este hecho en 20/12/2018 debería entrar en el contrato del 30/11. Y un trabajo hecho en enero debería entrar en el contrato firmado en enero.

Ahora mismo enlaza pero un trabajo en enero enlaza con diciembre y enero, por esta clausula :`AND fecha_tabajo > inicio_contrato`

He metido un `ROW_NUMBER` por si casualidad se puediese hacer `AND Min(rn)`.Pero va a ser que no.

Os dejo un [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ded9b4/5) y un [rexteter](https://rextester.com/BPPV66550) por si queréis probar

No hace falta decir que las tablas son de ejemplo y no tiene nada que ver con la realidad, por lo que modificarlas es totalmente inviable.

Comment: El fiddle no funciona. No sé a ti, pero a mi sqlfiddle me fallaba mucho, así que cambié a **[`rextester`](https://rextester.com)**.

Comment: Graceias @A.Cedano , lo paso a rexteter, no me importa copiar y pegar [aqui esta](https://rextester.com/BPPV66550)

Comment: Yo no veo claro el problema que expresas. Cuando reviso los resultados (de la 1ª tabla) en todos se cumple la condición: `fecha_trabajo` es mayor que `inicio_contrato` ... ¿cuál es el problema? ¿puedes indicar alguna fila donde no se cumpla la condición y te esté incluyendo el valor en la suma?

Comment: Claro la consulta funciona, pero no es lo que quiero. Un tabajo en diciembre tiene que coger el contrato de diciembre. Un tabajo en enero tiene que coger el contrato de enero. Con esa consulta, un trabajo en enero coge el contrato de diciembre y de enero. 
SI te fijas, la linea 6 y 11, es el mismo trabajo enlazando con 2 contratos diferentes. Cuando deberia ser 04/01  al contrato del 01/01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He sacado la fecha del siguiente contrato con [LEAD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) para luego poder hacer un BETWEEN y así ver los trabajos que están entre un contrato y otro.

Aquí tendrías todo sin agrupar:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    trabajo t 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *, LEAD(inicio_contrato) OVER (partition by id_trabajador ORDER BY inicio_contrato ASC) fecha_siguiente_contrato
                FROM contrato) c ON c.id_trabajador = t.id_trabajador AND fecha_tabajo BETWEEN inicio_contrato and COALESCE(fecha_siguiente_contrato, '29991231')
    INNER JOIN trabajador tr ON t.id_trabajador = tr.id_trabajador;
```

Y aquí el agrupado con el sumatorio:

```
SELECT
    SUM(c.sueldo)
    , tr.nombre
FROM
    trabajo t 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *, LEAD(inicio_contrato) OVER (partition by id_trabajador ORDER BY inicio_contrato ASC) fecha_siguiente_contrato
            FROM contrato) c  ON c.id_trabajador = t.id_trabajador AND fecha_tabajo BETWEEN inicio_contrato and COALESCE(fecha_siguiente_contrato, '29991231')
    INNER JOIN trabajador tr ON t.id_trabajador = tr.id_trabajador
GROUP BY
    tr.nombre
```

Creo que cumple con lo que necesitas.

Aquí tienes un [fork](https://rextester.com/VMCDNP77445) de tu rextester.

Comment: Claro claro, buscas el suiguiente y luego que cuadre dentro del intervalo. la verdad no lo habia pensado asi, y parece que todo esta de lujo. muchas gracias